# Apt-get uanble to locate package httplib and urllib

Tags: python

I am using Pi 4. So few days back I installed two libraries `httplib` and `urllib` to run a code. But recently I found out that both these libraries are missing. So when I try to reinstall them again using `sudo apt-get install httplib` it is showing `unable to locate package`. Please help.

Comment: Not Pi specific.  You need to find the package which contains the library.  Perhaps use apt-cache search on the library.

Comment: like `sudo apt-cache httplib`?

Comment: More like `apt-cache search httplib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a bit of digging I found out that the `httplib` library has been updated to `http.client` while the `urllib` is same, its atrributes have changed to some extent.